# Symfony2 getter constraints validation - What does they mean when they say "move the constraint to a property with the same name later"?

Tags: validation, symfony

I have started learn Symfony, I am reading the book, I would like to ask someone for help because I don't understand a phrase in the validation chapter, when they talk about getters constraint validation:

```
# src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author:
    getters:
        passwordLegal:
            - "True": { message: "The password cannot match your first name" }
```

> Now, create the isPasswordLegal() method, and include the logic you need:
>
> The keen-eyed among you will have noticed that the prefix of the
>   getter ("get", "is" or "has") is omitted in the mapping. **This allows
>   you to move the constraint to a property with the same name later (or
>   vice versa) without changing your validation logic.**

What does they mean when they say: "This allows you to move the constraint to a property...without changing your validation logic"?

I am sorry but I didn't understand it, could someone explain what do they mean? Move the constraint to a property...
What is the privilege of what the authors are saying?

Answer (score -1):

Look at Annotation tab, everything is there:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Author
{

    /**
     * @Assert\True(message = "The password cannot match your first name")
    */
    public function isPasswordLegal()
    {
       // return true or false
       return $this->firstName != $this->password;
    }
}
```

Now, while validation, isPasswordLegal() method will be executed. This is simple example, but this way you can validate more sophisticated dependences.

Comment: Thank you for your response, yes, I understand the annotation behaviour, what I still do not understand is the phrase "`This allows you to move the constraint to a property with the same name later (or vice versa) without changing your validation logic.`" in the context of the validated class... If you understand it, could you explain it to me in other words? Thank you

Comment: This does not answer the question. Why the prefix of the getters is omitted?